# How to inline a child div with another child div?

Tags: html, css

I have tried float, display inline-block. Flex does work but I cant use flex as it will inline every single child div and I dont want that. I basically want few boxes in the left and one box on the right that auto size the height accordingly with the height size of the child divs from the left. I have tried floating boxChildRight to the right/left vice verse and its not working.

HTML

```css
#sp {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.boxChildRight {
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.boxChildLeft {
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.prodInfo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.img {
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> PARENT DIV
  <div class="boxChildLeft"> CHILD
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildRight"> THIS CHILD DIV SHOULD BE ON RIGHT SIDE OF ALL OTHER DIVS
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the Graphical representation how you exactly want it to look...or explain more... :)

Comment: If you click run code you will see how its looking. I want the child box on the right bottom to be on the top of the first div to the bottom of the last div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;`

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Added */
}

#sp {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:relative; /* Added */
  padding-right:20%; /* Added */
  float:left; /* Added */
}

.boxChildRight {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%; /* Updated */
  border: 1px solid;
  position:absolute; /* Added */
  right:0; /* Added */
  top:0; /* Added */
}

.boxChildLeft {
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.prodInfo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.img {
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> PARENT DIV
  <div class="boxChildLeft"> CHILD
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildLeft">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="../shopImages/candles.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="prodInfo">
      <p1>Test</p1><br>
      <span id="sp"><p1>Test</p1></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxChildRight"> THIS CHILD DIV SHOULD BE ON RIGHT SIDE OF ALL OTHER DIVS
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated on your comment

> **box-sizing**
>
> In CSS, by default, the width and height you assign to an element is
> applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any
> border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to
> arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
> means that when you set width and height you have to adjust the value
> you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added. This is
> especially tricky when implementing a responsive design.

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**

Comment: Thanks that worked :)  I never seen this type of code before..
**{
    box-sizing:border-box; /* Added */
}

what does it actually do?

Comment: You can read about ***[box-sizing here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)***.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that although the `div`s are set to `80%` and `20%` - that does not include the border.

In order to include the border width within the overall `width` calculated for your elements, simply add:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

for your CSS. This way, each element will take the `border` property in concideration when calculating the element's `width`.

Comment: Thanks that was definitely part of the problem. what is the star  * ? i never seen that type of css code before

Comment: `*` means "everything" using the lowest specificity. All UI frameworks use this property (like Bootstrap / Material and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I think using position is not a good solution we can do without using position absolute.
Agree with 
`* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

This code is without using position absolute property:-

https://jsfiddle.net/oceh7f9q/